# do-while is not working as expected

Tags: c, gcc, do-while

I am new to c and writing a program in c on linked list. Its a simple program.

I am using it to enter number to list till user  wants.

The code is as :

```
do {
    system("clear");
    printf ("\nEnter a no to add to list : ");
    scanf ("%d",&num);
    append (&p,num);
    display (p);
    printf ("\n\nWhant to add more...(Y/N) : ");
    choice = getchar();
} while (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y');
```

When user enters choice, program exits...

I am using gcc compiler on linux [ubuntu] to compile and run it.

Comment: `if(DidYouDownVote()) cout << "Provide a reason." << endl;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `scanf` reads a number and stops reading from `stdin`, but when you enter a number you send the number plus the `\n` character.  That is what `getchar()` reads.  It is not a `y` or a `Y`, so the loop finishes.

Change your `getchar()` line with this one:

```
scanf(" %c", &choice);
```

...and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Put: `getchar()`;

before

`choice = getchar();`

To consume the `\n` character that is left in `stdin` after `scanf()`.

The code then results to:

```
do {
    system("clear");
    printf ("\nEnter a no to add to list : ");
    scanf ("%d",&num);
    append (&p,num);
    display (p);
    printf ("\n\nWhant to add more...(Y/N) : ");
    getchar(); //needed to consume the \n character
    choice = getchar();
    }while (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y');
```

Answer (score 1):

> `getchar()` returns the next character from the standard input (`stdin`)

When you press enter after the `scanf()` statement, a `\n` character got accumulated in the input buffer. Thus the value of `choice` set to `\n` automatically and the loop condition became false.

You can use `scanf()` instead of `getchar()` to read formatted data from `stdin` eventually to hold the value of `choice`.

```
do {
    system("clear");
    printf ("\nEnter a no to add to list : ");
    scanf ("%d",&num);
    append (&p,num);
    display (p);
    printf ("\n\nWhant to add more...(Y/N) : ");
    scanf(" %c", &choice);
} while (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y');
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work: `scanf("%c")` does receive the `\n`. You need an extra space before `%c` to get rid of all the spaces, tabs and newlines